# using assert with ts-node in mocha test

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

I created a `mocha` test in a `test.ts`

```
import * as assert from "assert";

describe('it', () => {
  it('should ', done => {
    assert.strictEqual(true, false);
    done();
  });
});
```

My `package.json`s `devDependencies`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.5",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4"
  }
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["mocha"]
  }
}
```

When running `ts-node`, I get this error:

`error TS2307: Cannot find module 'assert'.`

My commandline call is this:

`./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha -r ts-node/register test/test.ts`

Regular `tsc` throws no errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it via [this issue comment](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/216#issuecomment-253900198) on GitHub:

`types` in `tsconfig.json` needs to include `node`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["mocha", "node"]
  }
}
```